# Fast way to redraw gradient?

Tags: ios, zooming, calayer, gradient, drawrect

I need to draw (a bit) complex gradients programmatically. Here is my params.

```objective-c
#define SHADOW_OPACITY 0.35

const size_t num_locations = 4;
const CGFloat locations[num_locations] = { 0, 0.12, 0.42, 1.0 };
const CGFloat components[num_locations * 2] = { 0.0, 1.0 * SHADOW_OPACITY,
                                                0.0, 1.0 * SHADOW_OPACITY,
                                                0.0, 0.73 * SHADOW_OPACITY,
                                                0.0, 0.0 };
```

Three rings with opacity and a dashed ring inside. All works just fine.

```objective-c
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [self drawGradientInContext:context];

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, CIRCLE_STROKE_WIDTH);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);

        CGFloat dashLength = DASH_LENGTH(self.circleRadius);
        CGFloat dashArray[] = { dashLength, dashLength };
        CGContextSetLineDash(context, 0, dashArray, 2);
        CGContextAddArc(context, CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds), self.circleRadius, 0, 2 * M_PI, YES);

    CGContextClosePath(context);

    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathStroke);
}

- (void)drawGradientInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    self.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorspace, components, locations, num_locations);

    CGPoint gradientCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
    CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context,
                                gradient,
                                gradientCenter,
                                self.circleRadius - 1,
                                gradientCenter,
                                self.circleRadius + SHADOW_WIDTH,
                                kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
}
```

Well, I need to apply zoom.

```objective-c
- (void)zoom:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    effectiveScale = beginGestureScale * sender.scale;
    self.circleRadius = effectiveScale * BASE_RADIUS;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPinchGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        beginGestureScale = effectiveScale ? effectiveScale : 1.0;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Well, since that things are screwed up: it glitches as the hell!

[image]

What could I do there?

Comment: Use instruments and work out where time is being spent. My guess is you should cache the gradients instead of recalculating them all the time, but without instruments data, its a guess.

Comment: @jrturton I've got the idea in a lot of the posts around the internet but I don't know how to implement caching. Can't find any piece of code.

Comment: Like I say, check that's where the problem is first, if it is, I'll put in some sample code in an answer.

Comment: @jrturton Added a screenshot.

Comment: That looks like drawing the gradient is taking the time, not calculating it. Since you're redrawing the contents all the time, telling your layer to rasterize is probably doing more harm than good.